# Nginx rewrite to lower case

Tags: nginx, wordpress, case-sensitive

Good Day, I have a nginx server and a WordPress site. At the moment my pages are available by url with a different case (for example, about-us and AbOuT-Us opens the same page). How to redirect all pages to lower case, but keep the ability to open files with different case (for example, in Woocommerce there are files like Woocommerce.js)?